# dpkg error code

Tags: 14.04, apt, lts

So I'm new to ubuntu, everytime I try `sudo apt-get install` I get this

```
 ryan@ryan-nBook-4300:~$ sudo apt-get install
    [sudo] password for ryan: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libaudio2:i386
    libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
    libcups2:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386
    libgcrypt11:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgpg-error0:i386
    libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386
    libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libice6:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386
    libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
    libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libmysqlclient18:i386 libogg0:i386
    liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpulse0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386
    libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386
    libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-xml:i386
    libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtdbus4:i386 libqtgui4:i386
    libqtwebkit4:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386
    libspeexdsp1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386
    libtiff5:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libwrap0:i386 libxi6:i386
    libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386
    libxv1:i386
Use `apt-get autoremove` to remove them.

    0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
    5 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic (3.13.0-43.72) ...
    Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic)
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic:
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic; however:
    Package linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up manila-common (2014.1~git20140220-0ubuntu12) ...
    No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
    grep: /etc/manila/manila.conf: No such file or directory
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/manila-manage", line 74, in <module>
    from manila.openstack.common import gettextutils
    ImportError: No module named manila.openstack.common
    dpkg: error processing package manila-common (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of manila-api:
    manila-api depends on manila-common (= 2014.1~git20140220-0ubuntu12); however:
    Package manila-common is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package manila-api (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of manila-scheduler:
    manila-scheduler depends on manila-common (= 2014.1~git20140220-0ubuntu12); however:
    Package manila-common is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package manila-scheduler (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic
    linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic
    manila-common
    manila-api
    manila-scheduler
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    ryan@ryan-nBook-4300:~$
```

so I ran sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean

```
ryan@ryan-nBook-4300:~$ sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for ryan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ryan@ryan-nBook-4300:~$
```

and sudo apt-get autoremove

```
ryan@ryan-nBook-4300:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic (3.13.0-43.72) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up manila-common (2014.1~git20140220-0ubuntu12) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            grep: /etc/manila/manila.conf: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/manila-manage", line 74, in <module>
    from manila.openstack.common import gettextutils
ImportError: No module named manila.openstack.common
dpkg: error processing package manila-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of manila-api:
 manila-api depends on manila-common (= 2014.1~git20140220-0ubuntu12); however:
  Package manila-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package manila-api (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of manila-scheduler:
 manila-scheduler depends on manila-common (= 2014.1~git20140220-0ubuntu12); however:
  Package manila-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package manila-scheduler (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                        Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic
 manila-common
 manila-api
 manila-scheduler
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ryan@ryan-nBook-4300:~$
```

what you think @heemayl

Comment: Please put the output in command tags as well, so it's easier to read.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean` and then do `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Try the above commands and let me know what happens in the comment by tagging me i.e. put `@` in front of my name..

Comment: @heemayl I've posted the outcome

Answer (score 0):

I'd try `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
 -f, --fix-broken
           Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
```

Comment: no that doesn't help :(

Comment: What does this command output?